# How to learn Jackson to cast inheritors of abstract class?

Tags: java, jackson

I have a class:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
public class AppealTemplateDto extends AbstractDto {

    private List<AbstractFieldDto> fields;
}
```

This class contains list of `AbstractFieldDto` inheritors, e.g.:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InputFieldDto extends AbstractFieldDto {

    private String fieldType = FieldType.INPUT.name();
    private String text;
}
```

Totally, there are near 6-7 inheritors, & AbstractTemplateDto may contain any set of them.

Controller:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<AppealTemplateDto> create(@RequestBody AppealTemplateDto dto) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(service.save(dto));
}
```

When Jackson trying to parse `AppealTemplateDto`, it crashes with exception:

> Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of
>   `ru.appeal.template.dto.field.AbstractFieldDto`
>   (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either
>   need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or
>   contain additional type information

As I understand, Jackson can't define, how to cast incoming `AbstractFieldDto`. Please, advice me, what to do?

Comment: Add a default constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Annotation your are needing are:

```
@JsonTypeInfo
@JsonSubType

@JsonTypeName
```

Some explanation: if you have many implementation of your abstract type, Jackson can't guess which type is your json, you need to add a type name in json, for example as a new property (this is one of the strategies):

```
//tell to jackson where to find the type name
@JsonTypeInfo(   use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
// tell to jackson the implementations to scan
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = InputFieldDto.class, name = "input")
    //, ...
})
public class AbstractFieldDto {
}

//tell to jackson what is the type name in json
@JsonTypeName("input")
public class InputFieldDto extends AbstractFieldDto {

    private String fieldType = FieldType.INPUT.name();
    private String text;
}
```