# Does Jackson deserialization have a maximum for inhertiance depth?

Tags: java, json, jackson

In other words is there a limit on the depth of inheriting that can be achieved.
Currently I'm on a depth of 2, Grandparent -> Parent -> Child, and I'm hitting an issue where Jackson can de-serialize up to the Parent then throws a  `UnrecognizedPropertyException`. Which would be correct however the child class does possess that property and I believe I've added the correct Type information for Jackson to de-serialize the child.

This test shows the issue:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonPOJOBuilder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class JacksonInheritanceTest {

    @Test
    public void deserializeChildrenAsGrandParentList() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String grandparentsJson = "{" +
                "\"list\":[{" +
                "\"type\": \"parent\"," +
                "\"value\": \"child\"," +
                "\"someProperty\": \"foobar\"" +
                "}]" +
                "}";
        GrandParentList grandparents = mapper.readValue(grandparentsJson, GrandParentList.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(grandparents);
    }

    @Test
    public void deserializeParentAsGrandParent() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String parentJson = "{" +
                "\"type\": \"parent\"," +
                "\"value\": \"child\"" +
                "}";
        GrandParent grandparent = mapper.readValue(parentJson, GrandParent.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(grandparent);
    }

    @Test
    public void deserializeChildAsGrandParent() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String grandparentJson = "{" +
                "\"type\": \"parent\"," +
                "\"value\": \"child\"," +
                "\"someProperty\": \"foobar\"" +
                "}";
        GrandParent grandparent = mapper.readValue(grandparentJson, GrandParent.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(grandparent);
    }

    @Test
    public void deserializeChildAsParent() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String childJson = "{" +
                "\"type\": \"parent\"," +
                "\"value\": \"child\"," +
                "\"someProperty\": \"foobar\"" +
                "}";
        Parent parent = mapper.readValue(childJson, Parent.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(parent);
    }

    @Test
    public void deserializeAsChild() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String child1 = "{" +
                "\"type\": \"parent\"," +
                "\"value\": \"child\"," +
                "\"someProperty\": \"foobar\"" +
                "}";
        Child child = mapper.readValue(child1, Child.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(child);
    }
}

class GrandParentList {
    @JsonProperty
    List<GrandParent> list;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Parent.class,
                name = "parent")
})
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = GrandParent.GrandParentBuilderImpl.class)
class GrandParent {
    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    static final class GrandParentBuilderImpl extends GrandParentBuilder<GrandParent, GrandParent.GrandParentBuilderImpl> {
    }
}


@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "value", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child.class, name = "child")
})
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Parent.ParentBuilderImpl.class)
class Parent extends GrandParent {
    @JsonProperty
    private String value;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    static final class ParentBuilderImpl extends ParentBuilder<Parent, ParentBuilderImpl> {
    }
}


@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Value
@SuperBuilder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Child.ChildBuilderImpl.class)
class Child extends Parent {
    @JsonProperty
    private String someProperty;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    static final class ChildBuilderImpl extends ChildBuilder<Child, ChildBuilderImpl> {
    }
}
```

Comment: If it didn't do more than two it would have a problem, and if you have more than about 4 you have a problem.

Comment: This example is complete but not minimal. whatever there's no limit so far I know,  It looks to me that you didn't define "child " as a subclass of grandparent or parent,  and child is not anotated with jsontype. more example of jsonTypeName: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395909/how-to-learn-jackson-to-cast-inheritors-of-abstract-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to define inheritance with many Levels:

You want to deserialize a list of GrandParent which final type is "child"

```
  {
      "list":[{
          "type": "child",
          "someProperty": "foobar"
      }]
  }
```

and the inheritance tree is :

```
GrandParent
  Parent
    Child(someProperty:String)
```

You have to define your "type" attribute at top level,  @JsonTypeInfo(...)
 you can repeat it on sublevels but it is not required if you only serialize/deserialize grandparent.
Then on each parent level (classes Parent and GrandParent) you define the subtypes just as you did with     @JsonSubTypes.

the code

```
public class JacksonInheritanceTest2 {

    @Test
    public void deserializeChildrenAsGrandParentList() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String grandparentsJson = "{" +
                "\"list\":[{" +
                "\"type\": \"child\"," +
                "\"someProperty\": \"foobar\"" +
                "}]" +
                "}";
        GrandParentList grandparents = mapper.readValue(grandparentsJson, GrandParentList.class);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(grandparents);
    }


}

class GrandParentList {
    @JsonProperty
    List<GrandParent> list;
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Parent.class,name = "parent"),
        //@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child.class, name = "child")
})
class GrandParent {
    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

}


//@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child.class, name = "child")
})
class Parent extends GrandParent {
    @JsonProperty
    private String value;

}

@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child.class, name = "child")
})
class Child extends Parent {
    @JsonProperty
    private String someProperty;

    public String getSomeProperty() {
        return someProperty;
    }

    public void setSomeProperty(String someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }



}
```

The error you did:

- define many attribute type name, each for one parent level: you choose your attribute type name and use only one.
- in Json you did set the type name of the parent in the abstract: only the leaf type is important, the rest of the tree is deducted.

Side node: `Assertions` is from junit5, it does the same as `Assert` from junit4

Comment: So if I understand correctly. Out-of-the-box Jackson can only handle type-inference based on one property name? My problem is that I need to do type-inference based on two properties not one. I assumed that adding `@JsonTypeInfo` at different inheritance depths would allow Jackson to deduce which property would map to which depth and chain them together. Unfortunately it seems I'll need to write something custom for this. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @ByeBye no the type inference works as expected, your object only have one type at a time. You can't specify 2 types for an object (how would you do with java code?)

Comment: @ByeBy maybe I could explain the way the introspection works: 1. you give the grandparentclass with its config 2. Jackson find the annotation on the class-> get the type name of the object- then scan recursivly to find the real class associated to that name 3. Jackson instanciate that class (don't need to know the Parent intermediate class at this level) 3. it affects all field found giving the Child class- again all field of Parent are known by inheritance - don't need to specify Parent. In all theses 3 step you never need to specify that instance of "Child" is a "Parent"

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I can only specify the type-information in an annotation once (on the `GrandParent`) and I can only use one property for type-inference (the `type` property). I'll mark your answer as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set config on ObjectMapper object:

mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an answer to my question. Since it will result in Jackson simply ignoring `Child`'s `someProperty` property and return an instance of `Parent` instead of `Child`. Which is not the behaviour I expect.